# Which one is correct "died of" or "died from"?

Tags: nouns, phrasal-verbs

I read that died of disease is correct in context of disease and died from  is correct in context of accident. but I read in news that died from is also used in context of disease for instance:

> Happy Days actress Erin Moran believed to have ‘died from stage 4 cancer’ according to police statement.

Which one is correct ?

"Is died from cholera" correct sentence?

[Link to news](https://www.thesun.co.uk/tvandshowbiz/3405919/happy-days-actress-erin-moran-believed-to-have-died-from-stage-4-cancer-according-to-police-statement/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a physics joke that goes "it's not the fall that kills you; it's the sudden stop at the end". Similarly, if you fell twenty stories, we might say that you died *from* falling, but you died *of* massive trauma and bloodloss (caused by the fall).

There isn't a hard and fast rule about this, especially since cause and effect are often intertwined in medicine. Broadly speaking, you die *of* a direct cause; you die *from* an indirect cause. With cancer or cholera, which are both massive and systemic illnesses, both *died of cancer* or *died from cancer* would probably be acceptable to an English speaker.

There's a third common preposition here which is more metaphorical: when someone [dies by the sword](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/live_by_the_sword,_die_by_the_sword), for example, we don't literally mean that they died *from* a sword to the heart. Rather we mean that they were prone to violence, and themselves died violently.

Comment: "you die of a direct cause; you die from an indirect cause" Yet you die **from** a gunshot wound to the head, which is not what I would call indirect if it blew your brains out.

Comment: @Flater It's not that "die from" is only used for indirect causes, it's that indirect causes require the use of "die from" (and not "die of"). Perhaps "direct" and "indirect" are an oversimplification. It's more along the lines of proximate versus ultimate causes. You "die of" a proximate cause, whereas you "die from" an ultimate cause. A gunshot wound to the head can be considered an ultimate cause of death, so "die from" is appropriate there. (It's also proximate, so "died of a gunshot wound" would also be appropriate.)

Answer (score 2):

There are some specific rules as were outlined in the other answers but I would like to mention to non-native English users that all 3 are commonly used interchangeably.

Let me show you some examples and it may be clearer:

1. He died of cancer.
2. He died from cancer.
3. He died by cancer (this one is the most likely to raise questions with English speakers and does not *sound* as correct).

However, in this set of examples all 3 would be considered correct to any English speaker:

1. He died of a gunshot wound.
2. He died from a gunshot wound.
3. He died by a gunshot wound.

When talking about this subject, **die of**, and **die from**, are far more common than **die by** when speaking or writing.

You would more commonly see **"death by X"** as opposed to **"died by X"**.

Comment: 'He died by a sword wound' has barely any Google hits and sounds unidiomatic to my ears.

Comment: Not sure why you would downvote it? I clearly said that died by is not very common.

Comment: 'I would like to mention to non-native English users that all 3 are commonly used interchangeably.' [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=died+from+cancer%2Cdied+of+cancer%2Cdied+by+cancer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdied%20from%20cancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdied%20of%20cancer%3B%2Cc0) would seem to show that this is far from true. ELU expects answers to be accompanied by supporting evidence; otherwise, answers may be mere opinion (or even demonstrably unsound).

Answer (score 1):

There are three main ways to express that:

1. Die of
2. Die from
3. Die by

You use "die of" when when someone dies of a direct cause.

You use "die from" when someone dies from an indirect cause.

You use "die by" when someone dies by the means of something.

> He died of cancer.
>
> He died from smoking.
>
> He died by a bullet.

Comment: "You use "die from" when someone dies from an indirect cause" Yet you die **from** a gunshot wound to the head, which is not what I would call indirect if it blew your brains out.

Comment: How illness in brain is indirect cause? Like quoted in @john feminella answer falling from building is indirect cause

Comment: @Boris I will think of a better example. My reasoning was that it is the illness that kills you, not illness in itself. But it was badly worded.

Comment: @Flater because gunshot is indirect cause the real cause maybe that your cerebellum is damaged that is direct cause read another answer.